# Why is device.uuid returning as null in phonegap build?

Tags: android, ios, phonegap-build

I am developing an app through PhoneGap Build and have included the following plugins in my config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.8"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" version="0.2.6"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" version="0.3.7" />
```

I copy/pasted code from the documentation and created a test page within the app itself and all values returned for device are being returned as null.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I would like to know if I'm missing something or if there's any additional steps I need to take.  The code I used to test within the app is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log(device.cordova);
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onDeviceReady()">
    <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this on iOS? on iOS you're not allowed anymore to access device UUID

Comment: i am.  is there a reasonable substitute using phonegap build?

Comment: Have you access to the iAd unique id?

Comment: no.  i was also using the hydration feature of build, if it matters.  but apparently after updating the code, i deleted the version of the app that was on my development phone and reinstalled.  works fine now.

Comment: You should answer this question to close it.